# Remove Non Numeric Values Within SQL Select Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a value in a database column VALUE:

```
C_4327
```

I need to strip the non numeric text from this so that it just leaves the numbers.  I have tried using the REPLACE function within SQL but not I don't want to replace, just strip them out.  I was previously using PHP to do this:

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$row['VALUE']);
```

I'm retrieving the value in a SELECT statement.

Your help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you want to trim it and save again in DB or ?

Comment: I would like to display the answer in my while loop below.  So returning $valueID = $row['VALUE']; or similar if I did a REPLACE(...) AS companyID.. Is what I'm after but of course only displaying the numbers, not the other characters.

Comment: The replace function as part of a select statement will not change any data in the database.

Comment: Means that regex didn't work at all, then

Comment: I don't want to change anything in the database, I just want to strip it on the page.

Comment: This [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146292/how-to-replace-non-numeric-characters-in-mysql) might Interest you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the number at the end of the string, you can use the following arcane approach:

```
select reverse(reverse(value) + 0) as NumberAtEnd;
```

In your case:

- `value` ='C_4327'
- `reverse(value)` = '7234_C'
- `reverse(value) + 0` = 7234
- `reverse(reverse(value) + 0)` = '4327'

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for and it has worked.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a Function like that/.

```
  CREATE FUNCTION GetNumeric
 (
 @strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
 RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
 AS BEGIN
 DECLARE @intAlpha INT
 SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
 BEGIN
 WHILE
 @intAlpha > 0
 BEGIN
 SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
 SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
 END
 END
 RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
 END
 GO
```

then call the function as follows

```
   SELECT GetNumeric('123456789blahblahblah') AS filedname FROM your_table
```

you will get the answer : `123456789`

Answer (score 0):

simple way: how about substring...

```
select substr( value, 3 ) from mytable;
```

it works on your example - but not sure if your real data is more complicated.